# How to set Backbone and jQuery correctly with RequireJS

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm trying to work with `Backbone` using `RequireJS` but I'm having problems on seeing the `jQuery` `$` var from `Backbone`.

this is the require `config.js` file:

```
require.config({
baseUrl: "js",

paths: {
    // Aliases for libraries, so that we can change versions from here
    jquery: ["libs/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min", "libs/jquery/jquery-2.0.2.min"],
    handlebars: "libs/backbone/template/handlebars",
    lodash: "libs/backbone/template/lodash.min",
    requireLib: "libs/require/require-2.1.6-min",
    backbone: "libs/backbone/backbone-1.0.0.min",
    less:"libs/less/less-1.4.0-beta.min",
    helper:"app/helper",
    text:"libs/require/text-2.0.7"
},

shim: {
    "lodash": {
        exports: '_'
    },
    "backbone": {
        //These script dependencies should be loaded before loading
        //backbone.js
        deps: ["helper", "lodash", "jquery"],
        //Once loaded, use the global "Backbone" as the
        //module value.
        exports: "Backbone"
    },
    "jquery_cookie": {
        deps: ["jquery"],
        exports:"$"
    },
    "less": {
        exports:"less"
    }
}
});
```

This is my backbone's View file:

```
define([
"jquery",
"handlebars",
"lodash",
"helper",
"backbone",
"app/models/status_message",
"text!app/templates/status_message.php"
],

function ($, Handlebars, _, Helper, Backbone, StatusMessageModel, tmplStatusMessage) {

    var StatusMessageView =  Backbone.View.extend({
         events: {
            'click ': 'closeMessage'
        },
        initialize:function () {
            console.log("StatusMessageView.initialize");
            this.template = tmplStatusMessage;
            this.model = new StatusMessageModel();
            this.model.bind("change", this.render);
        },
        render:function () {
            //console.log("StatusMessageView.render");
            //console.log(this);

            var template = Handlebars.compile(this.template);
            var html = template(this.model.toJSON());

            if($("#status-message").length === 0) {
                $("body").append($(this.el).attr("id", "status-message").html(html));
            } else {
                $(this.el).attr("id", "status-message").html(html)
            }

            var self = this;
            var intro_timer = setTimeout(function () {
                $("#status-message").addClass("enter");

                var outro_timer = setTimeout(function () {
                    self.closeMessage();
                }, 5000);
            }, 500);
        },
        closeMessage:function () {
            $("#status-message").removeClass("enter");
        }
    });
    return StatusMessageView;
}
);
```

It seems that with this configuration I can't see `$` and I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object #<Object> is not a function
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: does helper require backbone?

Answer (score 1):

In the shim, add in jquery

For example

```
shim: {
    "jquery": {
        exports: '$'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've tried it but it steel won't work, in the network console everything seems to be loaded correctly, but `backbone` seems to be leaded first than `jquery`.

Comment: The information given is not complete. Some other settings are still required. Is there any reason u need to put this: requireLib: "libs/require/require-2.1.6-min" ?

Comment: no, I've removed it, but it still not working, also I never loaded it before.

Comment: Where is the code where you have called the view? For example, this https://github.com/mallim/boilerplate-r.js-jquery-backbone-handlebars/blob/master/www-root-dev/assets/js/app_main.js is loaded via App.initialize();